# using stored procedures with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, stored-procedures

I have a huge Wordpress plugin that uses Stored Procedures extensively. The entire site is based off this plugin. Therefore, we haven't been able to upgrade our version of Worpdress since 3.0. I am looking to bring Wordpress up to date, so the question is, is there any way I can get the current version of WordPress to allow my plugin to use Stored Procedures?

Perhaps there is a line I can put into the wp-config or wp-settings file to allow them?

Comment: I'm unclear on how upgrading WordPress would cause your plugin to no longer be able to utilize your stored procedures. WordPress does not create or use any SQL stored procedures, so the plugin's functionality should be more or less independent of WordPress.

Comment: well - it is the $wpdb connection... someone else posted this comment... wordpress does not support calling stored procedures from their database layer.    http://12u.hsbn.us/  - you can see the errors I get after upgrading. I looked into it and found many people have stated that wordpress does not allow stored procedures to be called... so I can technically open a new connection to use storedprocedures every time I want to call one, but that would be way too massive a task to implement

Comment: Were there core edits made to WordPress? Support for stored procedures hasn't been removed; it was never there. So something must have been done to allow the plugin to work prior to the upgrade.

Comment: well that would make sense as there was a great amount of customization - but I have no idea what/where that edit was. I guess that is what I am looking for now.

Comment: I would check in wp-db.php first: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L0

Comment: @mtinsley  - I did find this solution...

[https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-and-stored-procedure?replies=2]

however, this gives me the following wordpress error

Can’t select database
We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the database.